# Regress each column individually with the last column of a dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, regression, statsmodels

```
returns = df.pct_change(1) * 100
```

returns is the dataframe with dates as index, where I want to regress each column individually with the last column (which is ^BSESN) of the dataframe. Since there are more than 700 columns, I want to iterate through the columns. I also want to store the residuals, after each regression.
I used various versions of the following but I'm getting the same error constantly. I need to remove the rows which have NaN values during each individual regression (rather than removing rows with any column having nan value).

```
residuals = {}
for column in returns.columns[:-1]:
  selected = returns[['^BSESN', column]].dropna()
  reg = sm.OLS(selected[column], returns['^BSESN']).fit()
  residuals[column] = reg.residuals
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
MissingDataError: exog contains inf or nans
```

How can I remove the error? Any guidance on the best way to do this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the OLS call to

```
reg = sm.OLS(selected[column], selected['^BSESN']).fit()
```

See that `returns['^BSESN']` as in your original post didn't have any missing value dropped.

As some columns do not have any rows matching with `^BSESN`, you can add an if to ignore those columns:

```
residuals = {}
for column in returns.columns[:-1]:
  selected = returns[['^BSESN', column]].dropna()
  if selected.shape[0] > 0:
    reg = sm.OLS(selected[column], selected['^BSESN']).fit()
    residuals[column] = reg.residuals
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error now: ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity

Comment: It seems to me a column do not have any match with the BSESN column. Can you share the data? Add a `print(column, selected.shape)` right before the ols call to find out.

Comment: Yeah. You're right. Can you please suggest me how to overcome it? This is output: ('bse_closing_price', 11) (2129, 2)
('bse_closing_price', 14) (4440, 2)
('bse_closing_price', 289) (4439, 2)
('bse_closing_price', 301) (4436, 2)
('bse_closing_price', 363) (4440, 2)
('bse_closing_price', 365) (2603, 2)
('bse_closing_price', 400) (3394, 2)
('bse_closing_price', 415) (4243, 2)
('bse_closing_price', 443) (0, 2)

Comment: So, what do you want to do with those columns? To just ignore them add `if selected.shape[0] > 0:` before the call.

Comment: I also had a doubt regarding comparing resids with another dict containing only event dates to find the common dates and find 10 rows of residuals below and above the specific event date. Hence, I tried the following code (events is the dataframe containing 2 columns, co_code and event date):
`d = dict(tuple(events.groupby('co_code')))`
`carvalues = {}`
`for elem in d:`
  `if elem in resids:`
    `idx=resids.index.get_loc(elem)`
    `carvalues = resids.iloc[idx - 10 : idx +10]`
    `car_df = pd.DataFrame(carvalues)`
But I'm getting an empty dict as the output. How can i overcome this?

Comment: @AnishaBiswal it is hard to tell  without knowing what is going on with this `events` object. I think you should open a new question for this and describe it better what is the desired output and more about the data.

Comment: sure thing. I've posted the question here: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62904325/compare-2-dataframes-to-find-the-rows-containing-common-dates-and-obtain-the-n-r)